# SAS comparing data in a column

Tags: sas, compare

I'm very new to SAS and i'm trying to figure out my way around using it. I'm trying to figure out how to use the Compare procedure. Basically what I want to do is to see if the values in one column match the values in another column multiplied by 2 and count the number of mistakes. So if I have this data set:

```
 a b
 2 4
 1 2
 3 5
```

It should check whether b = 2 * a and tell me how many errors they are. I've been reading through the documentation for the compare procedure but like i said i'm very new and i can't seem to figure out how to check for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do if with PROC COMPARE but you still need to compute 2*a and you can't do that with PROC COMPARE.  I would create a FLAG and summarize the FLAG.  IFN function returns 1 for values that are NOT equal.  PROC MEANS counts the 1's where mean is percent and sum is count of non-matching.

```
data comp;
   input a b;
   flag = ifn(b NE 2*a,1,0);
   cards;
 2 4
 1 2
 3 5
 ;;;;
   run;
proc means n mean sum;
   var flag;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Proc compare* compares values in two different datasets, whereas your variables are both in one dataset. The following may be simplest:

```
data matches errors;
    set temp;
    if b = 2 * a then output matches;
    else output errors;
run;
```

Comment: Flagging and counting flagged observations works too (similar to data _null_'s answer, but I'd use proc freq instead of proc means)

Comment: The mean of 0/1 indicator is equal to the proportion of 1s.  It is a handy way to summarize such data when you only need to report the count of yeses. Apply PERCENTN format to mean to see it as percent 33.3%

Comment: Proc Compare can be used to compare data in the same dataset, but it cannot handle the 2*a portion. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0kmnl1zaofxdqn1s5kqz1c1txtu.htm